# Vagrantを使ったCakePHPのローカル開発環境の作業フォルダの場所

Tags: linux, cakephp, vagrant, virtualbox, composer

Mac OS X Yosemite
Vagrant
VirtualBox

Bitbucket
を使っていてBitbucketのリポジトリには

- hoge(開発中のcakePHPアプリケーション)
- composer.json
- composer.lock

既にVagrantにはApache+php5.5がインストールされています。

ここで

```
$ mkdir hoge
$ cd hoge
$ git clone ~
```

してcomposerを使ってインストールすると自動でcakePHPもインストールされてローカルで開発できるのはイメージできるのですが、この場合`git clone`するディレクトリは

- 自分のPC上（Vagrantfileが置いてあるディレクトリ）でしょうか？
- それとも`vagrant ssh`してログインした`/vagrant`上なのでしょうか？

上記のうちのどちらかだとした場合、`composer`自体のインストールもどちらか片方で構わないということになりますか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vagrantの共有フォルダ設定が行われていれば、ホスト側で`composer install`してもゲスト(Virtualbox)側で行っても結果は変わりません。

ホスト側で実行するのであれば、composer.phar自体もディレクトリ内に存在する必要はありません。

ただし、共有フォルダ設定がrsyncタイプの場合は、ホスト側で`composer install`後に、`vagrant rsync`でファイルを同期する必要があります。

Comment: 有難うございました。
Vagrantfileを編集して、早速`vagrant ssh`でログイン後、`/vagrant/hoge`内に`git clone ~` & `composer install`で問題無く共有できました。これでローカル（mac上）でソースコードをいじれます。

Answer (score 1):

composerのことは良くわからないので直接的な回答にはなりませんが、
vagrantに関して言うと、Vagrantfileに

```
config.vm.synced_folder <ホストOS側のディレクトリ>, '/vagrant'
```

という記述を加えると、指定したホストOS側のディレクトリをゲストOS側の`/vagrant` と共有させることができます。

この記述がないと単に`vagrant up`コマンドを実行したディレクトリ（端的に言うとVagrantfileのあるディレクトリ)が`/vagrant`として割り当てられます。

ゲストOS側をウェブサーバーとして扱い、ウェブブラウザでゲストOSにアクセスするやり方でWebページ等の開発をする場合、ホストOS上でソースコード編集をするのなら、上記共有ディレクトリ(`/vagrant`で共有しているディレクトリ)にソースコードを置き、ゲストOS側のphpなりapacheなりがそれと連動して動くよう設定しておく必要があります。