# Vagrant + CakePHP + CentOS 7.1でうまく表示されない問題

Tags: cakephp, centos, vagrant

VagrantでCakePHPをComposerからインストールしてローカル開発環境を作成しようと思っていたところ、以下と同じ状況になってしまい

[CakePHP cache was unable to write in Centos 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412433/cakephp-cache-was-unable-to-write-in-centos-7)
[AWSのEC2にCakePHP2.6を導入したのですがエラーが消えません。](https://teratail.com/questions/10268)

ファイルの権限を`chmod 777 -R temp`と変更してみましたがエラーが消えません。

```
Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 
'Cache engine "_cake_core_" is not properly configured.
Ensure required extensions are installed, and credentials/permissions are correct' in /webroot/hoge/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:186
Stack trace:
#0 /webroot/hoge/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_')
#1 /webroot/hoge/App/Config/core.php(354): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array)
#2 /webroot/hoge/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72): include('/webroot/hoge...')
#3 /webroot/hoge/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(431): Configure::bootstrap(true)
#4 /webroot/hoge/App/webroot/index.php(98): include('/webroot/hoge...')
#5 {main}
thrown in /webroot/hoge/Vendor/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 186
```

開発環境は

- centOS 7.1
- CakePHP 2.X

ほとんどの場合chmodで回避できた方が多い様ですが、私の場合は何か違う所が問題なのかもしれないのでどなたか同じ状況で解決策をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授願います。

追記：以下の設定で環境構築をしています。

Vagratnfile

```ruby
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.define "hoge" do |node|
    node.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.1"
    node.vm.hostname = "hoge"
    node.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.61"
    node.vm.network :public_network, ip: "192.168.11.61"
    node.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    end
    node.vm.synced_folder "./webroot", "/webroot", type: "nfs", mount_options: ["async", "nolock", "nfsvers=3", "vers=3", "tcp", "noatime", "soft", "rsize=8192", "wsize=8192"]
  end

end
```

composer.json ファイル

```json
{
    "name": "hoge",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.cakephp.org"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "cakephp/cakephp": ">=2.4.9",
        "cakedc/search": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
        "cakephp/debug_kit" : "2.2.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "Vendor/"
    }
}
```

core.php

```php
Cache::config('_cake_core_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_core_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration,
    'mask' => 0777,
));

Cache::config('_cake_model_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_model_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'models' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration,
    'mask' => 0777,
));
```

Comment: [VagrantでCakePHPを動かそうとした際に躓いたこと](http://qiita.com/deconcepter/items/bc90d6c2080eb19e9ff7)

Comment: どういう手順で環境を構築したのか（特にVagrantBoxの入手元）、現在はどのようなプロジェクト構成になっているのか、`app/Config/bootstrap.php` や `core.php` に何か手を加えたか、また `composer.json` の内容、などを明記していただけますか。

Comment: @holywise さん、有難うございました。追記の欄に構成、core.phpの設定を記述させて頂きました。

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/15086/10492 などを見る限りホストはMacで、ゲストの  /webroot はホスト側の webroot を見ているのですよね？ Mac は持ってないのでディレクトリを共有した状態でも可能かどうかわかりませんが、ゲスト側から app/tmp に `chgrp -R apache tmp` した後に、同じく app/tmp に `chmod g+s tmp` でどうでしょうか？

Comment: @holywise さん、おっしゃる通りホストマシンはMacで./webroot以下を同期しております。コメントを頂きました通り実行致しましたが同じ結果でした。ちなみに、ホスト名/phpmyadmin は正常に動いています。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決致しました。

[vagrant共有フォルダのパーミッションでハマった話](http://blog.buddying.jp/tips/2015-06-03/184/)

> どうやらvagrantの共有フォルダはコマンドで所有者や権限の変更できないらしい。

という事でしたのでVagrantfileを記事の内容と同じ

```
node.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant",
    :owner => "apache",
    :group => "apache",
    :mount_options => ["dmode=775,fmode=775"]
```

と設定しreloadしたら無事にローカル開発環境ができました。